# Copying files remotely with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am working from Windows Server 2012 R2 from that server I am connected to a internal network, to which there are numerous computers that I have access to.
What I want to do is based on a specific users IP address in that network I want to pull 3 specific files out of that computer and make a copy to a specified location on my server. The files are always located in the same file path location for each individual computer and have the same file name.

From what I understand is that I should be able to write a script to perform this.

Copy-Item -*ComputerName* -Path *filepath* -Destination *filepath destination*

I don't want to use the computer name as it is more convoluted to find, it would be nice to enter in the IP of the address I am pulling the 3 files from.

Or if there is an easier-quicker way to copy the files from the PowerShell environment that would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy files from a remove machine to e.g. your own, you could run

```
Copy-Item -Path '\\<ip>\<file>' -Destination <local path>
```

E.g. I tried running

```
Copy-Item -Path '\\10.0.0.10\C$\winbox.exe' -Destination c:\tmp
```

between two domain joined computers, to which my user account has access to, works fine. 10.0.0.10 is the remote machine.

Comment: That worked. 

If I want to pull 3 files from the same location is there a way to speed that up? 

Example:     
`Copy-Item -Path '\\10.0.0.10\C$\filea.exe' -Destination c:\tmp     
Copy-Item -Path '\\10.0.0.10\C$\fileb.exe' -Destination c:\tmp     
Copy-Item -Path '\\10.0.0.10\C$\filec.exe' -Destination c:\tmp`     


Or - if possible can I make a script and set a variable for the IP address. Then set the variable then run the script?
The file names are the same on every destination computer.